# How to move duplicate rows into columns with python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm having a very tough time trying to figure out how to do this with python. I have the following table:

```
NAMES    VALUE
john_1    1
john_2    2
john_3    3
bro_1     4
bro_2     5
bro_3     6
guy_1     7
guy_2     8
guy_3     9
```

And I would like to go to:

```
NAMES     VALUE1     VALUE2     VALUE3
john      1          2           3
bro       4          5           6
guy       7          8           9
```

I have tried with pandas, so I first split the index (NAMES) and I can create the new columns but I have trouble indexing the values to the right column.

Can someone at least give me a direction where the solution to this problem is? I don't expect a full code (I know that this is not appreciated) but any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After splitting the `NAMES` column, use [`.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape your DataFrame.

```
# Split Names and Pivot.
df['NAME_NBR'] = df['NAMES'].str.split('_').str.get(1)
df['NAMES'] = df['NAMES'].str.split('_').str.get(0)
df = df.pivot(index='NAMES', columns='NAME_NBR', values='VALUE')

# Rename columns and reset the index.
df.columns = ['VALUE{}'.format(c) for c in df.columns]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

If you want to be slick, you can do the split in a single line:

```
df['NAMES'], df['NAME_NBR'] = zip(*[s.split('_') for s in df['NAMES']])
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I kinda executed the df.pivot wrong in my own script, but then again, I learned some functions now that I didn't know of. Thanks a a alot!

Answer (score 0):

Split/Clean the data as explained by root; then you can also use

```
df_out=pd.crosstab(index=[df['NAMES']],columns=df['VALUE'])
```